# beginning programming in QT

Tags: c++, qt

i"m new to Qt, I'm trying to learn about it by developing a simple application. so the first thing i did is to create a main window that will have to tabs ! now i need to know how to add some buttons and other stuff (tables) to each tab ! could anyone give a hint how to do it ?
i have here the 3 files i made so far MainWindow.h main.cpp  MainWindow.cpp
thank you

```js
#include <QtGui>
#include <QAction>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QSplitter>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QStatusBar>
#include <QPushButton> //////
//#include "MatrixModel.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    setWindowTitle("EZ-MAT");
    //createActions();
    //createMenus();
    //createToolbars();
    //createWidgets();
    resize(1200,600);
    //Set Size Policies and Add Fillers
    //Set Tab Widget as central widget
}
```

```css
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class QAction;
class QLabel;
class QFindDialog;


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     MainWindow();

private slots:
    // void undo();
     // void redo();

private:
     void createActions();
     void createMenus();
     void createContextMenu();
     void createToolBars();
     void createStatusBar();


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

```html
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();

        window->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("EZ-MAT"));
        window->resize(1200, 600);

    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(window);
    QTabWidget *tabs = new QTabWidget(centralWidget);
   // QPushButton *Button_reset = new QPushButton(tabs) ;/////////////////////

    tabs->setFixedSize(1200, 600);
    tabs->addTab(new QWidget(),"Scientific Computation");
    tabs->addTab(new QWidget(),"Matrix");




    window->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    window->show();

    return app.exec();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new `QWidget`, and add some widget to it(also use layout) and add this widget to the tab. For example:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget;
QPushButton *push = new QPushButton;
layout->addWidget(table);
layout->addWidget(push);
widget->setLayout(layout);

tabs->addTab(widget,"text");
```

Comment: thank you @Chernobyl for your quick answer ! now after i add three tables and some buttons I want to label  table on the top of it each one and put the buttons between the first two tables and the last one

Comment: @AnonimO I showed main idea in my example, if you want to create more complex widget you should use a few different layouts. There are extremely useful articles in documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-and-layouts.html and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html

Comment: thanks so much for these links ! I'll try to work on them